# Webscraping using VBA into excel

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I'm making my first attempt at webscraping using VBA where I'm trying to scrape prices from our company's distributors for certain products into an excel file for our sales staff to analyse.

Essentially I'm taking the URL listed on my workbook then taking the price from the webpage and dropping it next to it.

My issue at the moment is I can't find the element and/or code to pick up the actual price on the webpage - here is my code at present.

```
Dim wkbDest As Workbook
Dim URLtab As Worksheet
Set wkbDest = Workbooks("Price Check list Gold and Silver.xlsx")
Set URLtab = Worksheets("URLs")
   
   Dim ie As Object
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
 ie.navigate ActiveCell.Value
 ie.Visible = True

    
Dim Price As Object
Set Price = ie.document.getElementByName("price-val")
```

I'll will use a product not produced by my firm to not go full mask off here:
https://www.force4.co.uk/item/Force-4/Hook-and-Moor-32m-with-Large-Head-Boat-Hook/VXY

Following this url, I inspect the element on the price on this webpage I get the following html code:

```
<    span class="price-val" content="183.95">183.95 </span    >
```

From here, I don't really know how to then export this price back to excel.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim ie As Object
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
 ie.navigate ActiveCell.Value
 ie.Visible = True
 
'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
Do While ie.Busy = True Or ie.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    
Set resultHtml = ie.document

For Each Tag In resultHtml.getElementsByClassName("price-val")
        With Tag.getElementsByTagName("span")
        
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Tag.innerText
            
        End With
    Next Tag

ie.Quit

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Worked perfectly for this site - hopefully I can use something similar for other distributors. Will give that a go on Monday - enjoy your weekend!